# e.stopPropagation() on Select Box Dropdown click

Tags: javascript, jquery, drop-down-menu, stoppropagation

I have a div editable with a blur function set.
When I click on select box the blur is called.

Can I stop the propagation of the click on the select?

I tried
http://jsfiddle.net/LZQSC/

```
$("#testInput").blur(function(){alert('blur');});

$('#testDropdown').bind('mousedown',function(e){
    //e.preventDefault();
   e.stopPropagation();
});
```

Is it possible? I tried different methods but nothing worked.

Answer (score 2):

You can unbind the blur function on select mouseenter and bind it again on mouseleave:

```
$("#testInput").blur(function(){alert('blur');});

$('#testDropdown').on('click',function(){
    // Do stuff
}).on('mouseenter', function() {
    $("#testInput").unbind('blur');
}).on('mouseleave', function() {
    $("#testInput").bind('blur', function() {
        alert('blur');
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/LZQSC/1/

Answer (score 1):

First of all:

The blur/focus change is not affected by stopping the propagation of the click. (Shall you use any of `stopPropagation`, `stopImmediatePropagation` or `preventDefault` - which only disables the default behavior of the click)

On the other hand:

If you'd like to retain focus on whatever element previously had the focus you should:

1. Remember who had the focus when beginning interaction with the select
2. Restore the focus when selection has been made

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/LZQSC/3/

```
$("#testInput").blur(function(){console.log('blur');});

(function(){
    // stores focused element reference
    var focusedElement;
    $('#testDropdown').on('mousedown', function(e){
            // on mousedown we get the focused element
            var el = $(':focus');
            // if this is other than the current select element 
            if(el.length > 0 && el[0] !== e.currentTarget){
                // save it in the var
                focusedElement = el;
            }
        }).change(function(e){
            console.log('changed');
            /* do stuff */
            // restore original focus
            console.log('setting focus on'+focusedElement.selector);
            focusedElement.focus();
    });
})();
```